# alternate for setup and deployment project in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

setup and deployment project template is missing in my installtion is there any alternate for that are please let me know the download link from msdn...

Comment: And what exactly are you wishing to setup and deploy? Are you only interested in solutions from MS?

Comment: What do you mean it is missing? Where have you checked?

Comment: it is not showing in my project templates so i guess that is missing... i want to create a setup for my published deploy project

Comment: Do you have Express Edition? That doesn't include it

Comment: I am voting to close this as it has been asked many times before in the form "what free software is available for building windows installers" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458900/free-software-for-windows-installers-nsis-vs-wix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the very similar questions that have already been asked

- [Free software for building Windows installers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458900/free-software-for-windows-installers-nsis-vs-wix)
- [What is the best choice for building Windows installers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers)
- [What is a good choice for installing .NET programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633255/good-net-application-installer)
- [Looking for a Windows Installer product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159598/looking-for-a-flexible-windows-installer-product-with-a-powerful-scripting-langua)
- [What is the best Windows installation file creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173307/best-windows-installation-file-creator)
- [Recommend a Windows packaging and deployment app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927851/packaging-application)

Answer (score 1):

An Alternative would be the [NSIS Installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

*P.s.: Yes, I've read his question...*